# How to pass data from asp.net to javascript after pressing a button

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am working on a pop up when a button is clicked on asp.net. Currently when the button is clicked, the values will pass in to a database and the method will return a int 1 value if the data insertion is successful. Then when the return value reached the if statement, i want to pass in a created variable to javascript to initiate a pop up.

```
    try
    {
        travelDetailsDAO tdDAO = new travelDetailsDAO();
        int insCnt = tdDAO.insertTravelDetailsInfo(tripName, startDate, endDate, country, description, expectedExpense);
        if (insCnt == 1)
        {
            ValueHiddenField.Value = "passed";
        }
        else
        {
            errorMessageDetails.Text = "Unable to insert travel details, please inform system administrator!";
        }
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        errorMessageDetails.Text = "Reached Catch!";
    }
```

Javascript code:
i want to continuously receive the hidden input value from the aspx without using setInterval but not sure how. And this javascript code is to receive the variable from the hidden input and alert the different text.

```
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
    var GettingValue = document.getElementById("ValueHiddenField").value;
    if (GettingValue == "passed")
    {
        alert("Worked");
    }
    else 
    {
        alert("failed")
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you want to pass hidden field value to JS code and show `alert()` message afterwards? Please explain further what you want to do by passing from code behind to JS variable using server control.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Yup i changed it. what i wan to achieve is the javascript side code to continuously receive the hidden input value to allow the different alerts when the button is clicked

Comment: Instead of `document.getElementById("ValueHiddenField").value;`, try `document.getElementById("<%= ValueHiddenField.ClientID %>").value;` if the `ValueHiddenField` is a hidden field server control, because the hidden field ID may be different with default setting.

Comment: i tried that but it says the value is null

Comment: Kira what you are describing is a common problem with ASP.net  The issue is really that you are trying to combine your code behind logic with javascript functionality and you cant really do effectively because......when you click a button that calls asp (back end/code) you are sending execution back to the server which then posts back (partial or full) to the calling page. So your call to the Javascript has to be initiated  from your back end code, commonly using "RegisterStartupscript". This is why I posted the answer I did I will my explanation to my answer hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the `RegisterStartupScript` method.

Here is a [case - RegisterStartupScript](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/422905/open-a-popup-window-using-javascript-Window-open) that allows you to open a window.

*You will need to add a script manager control on your page

P.S. this is a common problem with ASP.net  The issue is really that you are trying to combine your code behind logic with javascript functionality and you cant really do effectively because......when you click a button that calls asp (back end/code) you are sending execution back to the server which then posts back (partial or full) to the calling page. So your call to the Javascript has to be initiated  from your back end code, commonly using "RegisterStartupscript"